# Disable scroll on site and use scroll to resize image

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site i have an image width 100% width and when the user is scrolling down i resize the image untill a certain point.

While the image is is resizing on scroll, i don't want the rest of the site to scroll. When the correct image size is reached scroll should be enabled so the user can scroll freely.

As i remember Apple used this effect on the iMac product site once. Maybe there is a library or some better way to accomplish this.

I have tried to use absolute position on my page container div and then adjust the position on scroll also. `$('.profile.absolute').css('top',scrollY+'px');` It works in principle but on mobile it jumps a few pixels op and down and does not look good.

How can i make the page "freeze" until the image has the correct size?

```
.photo_main_float {
    position: fixed;
    width:calc(100vw - 30px);
}

window.onscroll=function() {
    var scrollY=window.scrollY;
    var scrollR=115;

    if (scrollY > 0 && scrollY < scrollR && $('.photo_main').hasClass('photo_main_float')) {
        var scrollSoFar = scrollY / scrollR * 100;        
        var img_size = 100-scrollSoFar;
        $('.photo_main').width('calc('+img_size+'% - 30px)');
    }
    if (scrollY > 0 && scrollY > scrollR) {
        $('.photo_main').removeClass('photo_main_float');
    }
};
```

Comment: Keep in mind that specifically asking for a library or such is a good way to get your question closed. Regardless, [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/) is a popular animation library. You could use GreenSock's [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/) plugin to tie animations to page scroll. As far as making the page freeze, you don't. Instead, you include a gap in the page and move the element along with the scrolling (either by updating its position or by using `position:fixed`) so that it appears to stay in place.

Comment: ah of cause. Make it fixed and insert a temporary div with a height that activates the scroll. Thanks a lot. And thank to the link, i will check it out.